# Icons in chrome developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, icons

What are these icons in CSS class I found under chrome developer tools?

Are those related to LESS/SASS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be the `construction` emoji: https://emojiterra.com/construction/

Is `construction` or `barrier` part of the classeName?

You seem to have an app or extension that automatically replaces buzz words with emojis